# Should I ask for a recommendation letter from a professor who I know from an industry training program?

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter

I joined a company after graduation. And our company often offers funding for professors in academia. In exchange, these professors usually would attend our training programs to teach some lessons related to their fields. 
Recently, I decided to apply for a Ph.D. position. Shall I ask for a recommendation letter from one of the professors who happen to be in the research field I want to do?

Comment: How well do they know you and who are your other referees?

Comment: My other referees are the professors I once worked with. I published one paper with one and worked as visiting student with another one. But the third referee is really difficult to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned in a comment that you already have two referees, one of whom you have published a paper with. I imagine this person will give you a very strong reference, and that the details of your other referees may not matter so much.

You also say that the professor you worked with is in the field you are interested in, which means they are well placed to talk about your ability and potential in that field, therefore using them as a third reference is a good idea.

You can find advice about emailing them to request a reference [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90725/how-should-i-phrase-an-important-question-that-i-need-to-ask-a-professor).