# How to respond to the Foreign Professor

Tags: graduate-admissions, email

How can I respond to the professor for the below mail:

> Dear XXX, Thank you for your information.  I will have additional
>   time to review this week.
>
> Regards,

Thanks in advance, for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I phrase an important question that I need to ask a professor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90725/how-should-i-phrase-an-important-question-that-i-need-to-ask-a-professor)

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing the context it's hard to say, but this looks to me like an email that doesn't need a reply.

Comment: Prof are going to review my profile in next week, as far I understand.
So, no need to answer the prof right now, right?

Comment: Professors tend to be very busy people, so I find it's best to keep your emails to them at an absolute minimum.