# Homework is to be submitted according to a guideline that is nowhere to be found

Tags: etiquette, undergraduate, coursework

I am a new transfer student from a much, much smaller university to a semi-prestigious one. The first set of homework has been assigned (due in three weeks) and says it should be “submitted according to the TA’s guidelines”.

However, I do not see any guidelines on the university’s site, nor on the TA’s site. I also have not met the TA yet, and office hours have not been posted.

Whom and how should I ask for clarification?

- Should I email the professor directly?
- Should I email one of the three TAs (I don’t know which one will be marking)?
- Something else?

---

If it is relevant, the subject is mathematics and homework is graded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I phrase an important question that I need to ask a professor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90725/how-should-i-phrase-an-important-question-that-i-need-to-ask-a-professor)

Comment: This doesn't need to be difficult: you can just ask any of the people running the class, either in person or by email.

Comment: Yes, yes. and yes (email all three TAs).

Comment: @jakebeal since I am a new student (and the environment is very different from my former university), I am unsure how to proceed. It also isn't too important yet as there is still some time before it is due. I would normally ask my classmates, but since I am new, I haven't gotten to know anyone well enough yet

Comment: @jakebeal I'll try asking the people I sit beside when I have class on Monday

Comment: @JeffE Are you saying yes to the 3 separate questions, or saying "yes" to only emailing the 2 TAs?

Comment: The most common arrangement is that each TA is assigned to specific sections, and marks the papers of the students in those sections. Probably each TA gets to set guidelines for submission (submit during class, submit to a central drop box, etc) according to their own preference.  As Nicole Hamilton says below, your own TA will surely explain their procedure when you meet them, so no need to contact anyone until then.  There's a fair chance your TA hasn't even decided yet as to what they are going to do.

Comment: I'm answering "yes" to all three questions.  Email everybody.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to submit anything for 3 weeks and it's so early in the term that you don't even know who your TA is, I would wait until you do.  You can't be the only one who has no idea what your TA wants if you don't even know who it is.

There's a pretty good chance you'll get a short orientation in your section where the expectations will be explained and you can ask questions.