# How do I respond to my professors email about recommendation letter? He is out of the country for sometime and his FIL is ill

Tags: graduate-school, email

I have contacted my professor about recommendation letter for my applications to PhD programmes. He has provided letters for few of my application.

Right now I am applying to few more universities and have contacted him again to provide few more letters in support of my application. He responded by saying that he is in a different country and his father-in-law is ill. He said he would provide the letters once again when he is back in the country. How should I respond to his email? I feel bad about constantly bothering him about letters of recommendation.

Comment: Please consider a better title that describes your problem.

Comment: Is the title okay now?

Comment: Or this: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/111378/how-should-i-phrase-a-question-about-an-ordinary-academic-matter-to-a-professo

Comment: @Federico Thank you. I will go through the other questions.

Answer (score 2):

Just say thank you and send best wishes for the health of his father in law. Nothing more is needed.

Three is no need to feel bad about your request. It is perfectly normal and natural.

Comment: How do I word it? I am struggling with how to convey my wishes for his FIL's recovery as well for constantly bothering him for LORs over email. Any example would be beneficial. Thank you.

Comment: Just a simple phrasing and a couple of lines. Use your own words, but nothing much more complex than what I suggested. There isn't a real problem here. He will appreciate "best wishes". Don't apologize for asking him for a normal request. That part is fine without more than "thank you".