# What's the best way to ask a professor for their syllabus before the term starts?

Tags: professorship, email, syllabus

"I am taking your course in Spring 2021. Is it possible for you to send the syllabus if there is one ready?"

Is the wording okay?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I phrase a question about an \*ordinary academic matter\* to a Professor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/111378/how-should-i-phrase-a-question-about-an-ordinary-academic-matter-to-a-professo)

Comment: Thanks for your question, but please bear in mind that Academia.SE is not a secretarial/proof-reading service.  It is likely that your question will be closed in its present form.

Answer (score 2):

LGTM.  I think it's very fair to ask a professor if you can see the syllabus for their class before you sign up.  How else would decide if it's something you'd like to do?

Answer (score 1):

Typically an email with the phrasing you had is enough. Most professors recognize that it’s a common thing for students to be curious about what they will be learning.