# How to make a complaint about grades?

Tags: graduate-admissions, professorship, grading, projects

My professor announced the grades. He told us in each part what grades we had.
My oral presentation for the project was way better than other students. But he just gave me 89 for oral and gave others 88. 
I think it is not fair at all, because most of the students were not clear or the did not consider timing. He also told me that "your presentation was very good". 
Also, I performed very well on the final exam but he also did not give me the 100. I think it is not fair.

How can I make a complaint? What should I write?

Comment: Your student guide should have information in it about whatever the grade revision process is for your university

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I phrase an important question that I need to ask a professor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90725/how-should-i-phrase-an-important-question-that-i-need-to-ask-a-professor)

Answer (score 3):

In principle, at least in some places, you can request an independent regrading for your written exams, as far as I know. The upside is, apparently, a few extra points and, possibly, going one shade of grade up (if you have anywhere to go; normally 90%+ means an A anyway). The downsides are

1) Getting at odds with your instructor (never really pays off, if you ask me)

2) The risk that your grade will get even lower (unless you are totally sure that your answers are 100% correct)

3) Creating a reputation of somebody who complains too much about too minor issues.

It is up to you to decide if you want to play this game. If you do, just visit the department chair office and politely ask what the rules for making such requests are.

As to the oral presentation, it is gone. Nobody (neither you, nor your instructor) can prove beyond doubt anything about what happened there now. You'll just enter a long and mainly pointless discussion about who heard what and how to measure "fairness". Besides, it is one of the cases when the scores are going to be at least partially subjective no matter what.

Comment: I was part of a large shared project (6 courses ) and we videoed every presentation including the q&a at the end. Two reasons, 1 to give as feedback(not the q&a part) and to have evidence for any attempt of “I deserve X grade due to Y”. One student wanted X, but his input showed it was not correct...

Answer (score 0):

For now, I guess, the only think you should do is asking the students previously took this course from same professor, about his grading at the end. Maybe that one point really weighs much.
Also I have seen in many lecturer that giving a 100 grade over 100 is almost tabu. Sometimes you clearly outstand everyone but they always find a thing or two to curb a point.
After final grades given and you still think it is unfair,  I suggest you one to one talk with him about grade, in a way curious about why your grade is lower, not in a furious way. 
After all of that, if that grade is really really detrimental for your career, consult the regulations on your university and department about how to proceed on regrading demand.