# How to remind professor of a gift that they promised but haven't delivered?

Tags: email, communication, gifts

I answered a challenging question in one of my courses by e-mail. The professor replied that I won a gift card for buying stuff from the university.

It has been 2 months he has not issued the gift card.
Is it normal if I ask him to issue it?
If yes, what is the appropriate way?

Answer (score 7):

This seems like a great opportunity, actually. If you can go visit him in the office just ask if the gift card offer is still open. He will probably slap his forehead for forgetting about it. Keep it low key. But it is a good thing to make a connection like this. Even bumping in to him in the hall would be a way to raise it.

If you can't visit in person, an email would be fine. Just remind him of the question you answered and ask if he forgot about the gift card or whether some issue came up. Just be direct. You don't need to be bashful about such things.

Edited to add: It would also be good, no matter how you do it, to thank the professor for the problem you solved and for the offer of the gift card. The reason for thanking him for the problem is that it, I hope, increased your learning.

Comment: the problem is that it is hard to meet him and I have to write an email. Writing it through email is tough.  I do not want to be rude since he might think that I like money.

Comment: When you write, also thank him for both the problem you solved and the gift he offered. Nothing rude about that.

Comment: @Elena93 No one *dislikes* money

Comment: @Elena93 If you have to write an email just keep it short, concise and polite. The advice in https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90725/how-should-i-phrase-an-important-question-that-i-need-to-ask-a-professor applies.