# How to approach research advisor after failing first semester of master's program?

Tags: masters, grades

So, I started grad school during the Sep 2020 session in lockdown. Within a month or two, I was struggling to reach deadlines for assignments of all the courses. I found the online mode of classes very tedious and just could not perform to my best. The monotonous lifestyle and the pressure of graduate work became too much for me. In the end, I was feeling so demoralized and anxious that basically, I didn't attend the last month of classes. So I got an 'F' in 3 of the 5 courses as I missed the assignments, presentations, exams, etc.

Now I have to face my research advisor about everything that happened. I don't know how to approach him regarding this. I know it reflects poorly on my performance and I feel awful. But I can't change what has happened.

I really do want to turn my situation around and successfully complete my grad school. Please let me know any suggestions for how to proceed.

Comment: 3 of 5? That's really bad, normally if you cut you losses and salvage the majority of classes you might have some leeway.

Comment: You should probably talk to the grad director first. If you can't avoid getting dropped for grades it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Just shoot the advisor an email in which you *briefly* say what you've told us here and you want to meet about next steps. Don't over-explain, and make it factual. Don't make it look like you're trying to get sympathy or make excuses. Something like, "Due to difficulties with the pandemic, I did not perform as well as I would have liked. Would you be available to meet to discuss next steps?" Hopefully your advisor is a decent human being and has some compassion, though they may have little or no control over what the next steps actually are. Still worth at least touching base with them.

Comment: @transitionsynthesis Looks like something to put in the answer box rather than a comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I phrase an important question that I need to ask a professor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90725/how-should-i-phrase-an-important-question-that-i-need-to-ask-a-professor)

Comment: Aside from the actual question, think about whether you need a break until things settle down. Also think about talking to a professional counsellor both about your study and your mental health.

Comment: You need to get help locally.  The pandemic is a new thing for everyone, so we cannot advice you on what to do.