# How to identify potential advisors for a masters program in the US

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters, computer-science

My apologies if this question is asked elsewhere or is extremely trivial, but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer anywhere...

I am currently a math major (US university) in my junior-year, looking to apply to a computer science masters program in the US later this year.

I've heard from many different sources that in general, it might be beneficial to reach out to faculty/professors before I apply (given that I genuinely have something meaningful to ask or talk about).

But... I don't really understand how to find these faculty/professors? I understand it will be different for every program, but in general how would you tell which professors are advising masters students?

I guess this question just boils down to my lack of understanding with the advisor-student relationship in a masters program. For example, is every professor required to take in masters students every year? What about adjunct/associate/assistant professors?

In the universities I plan to apply to, I have identified some faculty whose research I find interesting, but I can't figure out if they advise masters students, as they only list their PhD students on their websites. Should I just contact them, and ask if they advise masters students?

Thank you!

Comment: "Should I just contact them and ask if they advise masters students?" Yes! Unless you have a crystal ball, that's the only way to find out :) You can search on here for info on how to write emails to professors and get an answer, e.g. https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90725/how-should-i-phrase-an-important-question-that-i-need-to-ask-a-professor.