# Offered to do something for a professor

Tags: professorship

I'm in an unpleasant situation since I offered to do an interview with a professor, but unfortunately it has been one month and lack of communication between the professor and me and I'm no longer a student at the university. What would be the best way to communicate the urgency of same to the professor and also indicate that my priority has shifted?

I'm looking for the most appropriate way to ask the professor that I need him to reply, and be done with this interview so I can move on some better goals in life.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What kind of interview? Why is it urgent? How has your priority shifted? And what do you mean by "I offered to do an interview with a professor"? Please provide adequate details (does not have to be too specific, but currently it is too broad and unclear).

Comment: It's an academic interview done to ask the lecturers how did you do this that etc. I'm no longer a student (and on a job now).

Comment: It's still very unclear why you "need" to do the interview... if you're on a job not related (?) to the course you took, or whatever it was you were doing (teaching assistant?) Why is it "offering to do something _for_ the professor"? Does it potentially benefit _them_ in some way? Etc.?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I phrase an important question that I need to ask a professor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90725/how-should-i-phrase-an-important-question-that-i-need-to-ask-a-professor)

Comment: Are you interviewing the professor or is the professor interviewing you?

Comment: I have already interviewed him - but he is not convinced about the answers (that he himself gave) and is replying after 10 days time and saying he is busy. But I am also no longer a student to leverage so much time for him.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To be polite, send a note that you are no longer a student and are now employed. Apologize for the delay and, assuming it is true, offer to provide any information the prof might need.

Pretty straightforward, actually. But making your absence clear would be good, so that he can change any expectations.

Comment: Can you help me frame this? (I was told by time that he is busy and I should respect his time, but same does not be happening from his end! - I am even a student)

Comment: Just keep is short and to the point. Letting him know you are still available (if you are) is plenty. Then it is up to him to follow up if he thinks it necessary.

Comment: I am no longer available and honestly want to be done with it (When I told him I am no longer a student - he said I can contact him via my personal email ID. I thought it was dumb). Please help me a response for him!

Comment: (Also, I don't know who downvoted you - it was solid response from you- thank you !)

Comment: How about this ? I just wanted to let you know that I'm going to be starting my new job soon and as you know that it can get quite stressful. I was hoping to be submitting your interview this week. If you notice I have already made comments and some suggestions. It is required by you to accept them as per your wish. I hope you can understand my situation.

Comment: The next to last sentence is a bit too aggressive. How about "I hope you can accept them as sufficient." Also note that downvotes are a trivial matter. Some of my best work is downvoted quite a lot. ;-)

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that I'm going to be starting my new job soon and things have been quite stressful for me in last few weeks. I was hoping to be submitting your interview this week. If you could see the document, I have already made some suggestions. I hope you accept them as sufficient. Thank you! ? Is it OK ?

Comment: (Ah! I see no worries then)