# Requesting editor to transfer a manuscript to another journal

Tags: peer-review

My manuscript has been in review for several months. I would like it to be published soon because it is supposed to be part of my thesis. I have already contacted the editor and was told that they are having trouble finding reviewers. At the same time, there is another journal within the publisher, even more relevant to my manuscript, in which, from what I noticed, the review time is much shorter (probably they have a larger base of reviewers). Am I allowed to ask the editor to transfer my manuscript to this other journal in order to speed up the review process?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I phrase an important question that I need to ask a professor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90725/how-should-i-phrase-an-important-question-that-i-need-to-ask-a-professor)

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like

Comment: Review time is pretty noisy.  Be patient.

Comment: Is it required for your work to be published to be part of your thesis/to graduate?  (I'm trying to understand your second sentence.)

Comment: What is the standard time for reviewing a paper in your field?  It is hard to answer this without know that.

Comment: @Kimball FWIW, in Russia the entirety of the PhD thesis is supposed to be "peer reviewed", with key points being (ideally) published or, at least, presented at conferences. And it's all too common for PhD students to find themselves needing 2-3 published papers and only a few months before graduation... And I'm suspecting a similar issue on the OP's side.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't do that at all.  Firstly, I think there's a small chance you'd be burning bridges with the editor and that journal, and secondly because reviews take time and you probably have little real reason to *really* need your thesis published quickly.

Lastly, if you really wanted to move your manuscript to another journal, the right way to do it is to contact the current editor to withdraw your submission, and simply resubmit to the other journal.  There's zero reason to ask for a transfer.  There is no set work flow for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask, but generally speaking you can ask anything. But an alternative would be to suggest reviewers to them. That is also normally acceptable and common practice for some journals.

If you ask for a transfer you might phrase it as a question rather than a request: "Would it make sense to transfer the paper to X, and is that even possible?"

And note that starting over with another journal might not actually speed it up, since it will be starting over.

But, talk this over with your advisor, who might, among other things, provide suggestions for reviewers as well as general advice.

Answer (score 0):

If the other journal is published by the same publisher, there's a high chance that the two journals use the same editorial management system (EMS), and furthermore the EMS might even already be configured to facilitate easy transfers between the journals.

So yes, you can ask, and the editor might even be able to do the transfer for you (or if they can't, the publisher can operate the EMS for them). I wouldn't mention review times though, just say the other journal is more suited and you would like to transfer there.