# How to approach professors when I am changing lab?

Tags: phd, advisor, united-states

I am a second-year Ph.D. student and due to some unavoidable circumstances, I have decided to leave my current supervisor/lab. I tried to resolve all the issues but apparently, the supervisor told me it would be best for both of us if I move to another lab.

Now I am really worried and stressed about how I am gonna get a new lab. How do I approach other professors? I know that changing labs in the middle of the Ph.D. is not very uncommon but I am afraid if other professors think bad of me because I had to leave a lab.

I am an international student, which makes things harder for me. I am really traumatized, depressed, worried, and frustrated. I had a lot of motivation and passion when I started but because of the rude behavior of the supervisor, I am just the opposite now. I really don't know how to approach others or what to do in this situation. It will be very helpful if experienced people can suggest me in this situation.

Thanks.

Comment: That will depend a lot on details you don't mention, in particular whether your current supervisor is going to support you in trying to find a new lab.

Comment: He said he would help me find a new lab if needed.

Comment: So you likely have some idea of what other professors in the department are doing. Pick a few of them and go schedule a discussion of what the options might be. They will probably know there are issues and you will be looking.

Comment: @JonCuster yeah, I have an idea of the work of other professors. I am mainly worried if they have an opening or not at this time of the year.

Comment: That is a valid worry, but the way to get an actual answer is to go talk to them. You might also have a chat with the department chair (or grad chair) about the process and what happens next.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I phrase an important question that I need to ask a professor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90725/how-should-i-phrase-an-important-question-that-i-need-to-ask-a-professor)

Answer (score 2):

OK, first take a deep breath, relax a bit, and focus on what you can do about the situation. Students changing advisors (for many different reasons) is not all that unusual - any reasonably sized department will have this happen every year or so.

First, based on a comment you made, your advisor will help you 'if needed'. Fine, but you have work to do as well.

Second, you might want a meeting with the department chair (or grad chair depending on the structure). Talk about the issue, ask for help and advice on finding a new advisor. Listen to them.

Third, realize that your issues with your advisor are known, if only by rumor or off-the-cuff chats, with most of the professors in the department. They have been around, seen people change advisors - it is all a normal thing, except to you (since this is your first time). Relax.

Fourth, you've been around for 1.5 years or so, and likely have a handle on what different professors do, and what their students in your year are doing. Select three or four as a start, get appointments, and go talk to them about opportunities to join their group. Perhaps a few turn down the appointment request since they don't have funding. Find replacements for them. This may cause you to look further afield than you might like. Investigate further - in 40 years I've never had a research problem that was uninteresting at all.

Good luck, focus on the future.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I am just nervous about how to approach other professors. I know everyone knows that changing lab is not a new thing but as you said - the first time for me. This is making me nervous and worried.