# How to ask your PhD promotor for a letter of recommendation for another PhD position

Tags: phd, recommendation-letter, supervision, quitting

I may quit my current PhD position after a year and a half due to supervision-related reasons. My promotor is the professor who is head of team (and supervised my master thesis), while I am currently supervised by another academic. My promotor is a very kind and considerate person. I have looked up another PhD position in a different country that suites my interests best. How to ask him for a letter of recommendation for the new PhD position?

I don't have any publications yet. My current promotor is currently evaluating a paper I wrote from my master thesis. I may also write another one from my master thesis. I would like to continue my work on these papers with him - how do I approach this situation without affecting the review process by him?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I phrase an important question that I need to ask a professor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90725/how-should-i-phrase-an-important-question-that-i-need-to-ask-a-professor)

Comment: "Promotor" means your current primary PhD advisor? I think this is uncommon terminology in most places, except perhaps where you are.

Comment: @BryanKrause: this indeed is the terminology used in the Netherlands and Belgium for the PhD supervisor.

Comment: Do you have a scholarship or a research assistant position (in a project)? And what do you mean by "reasons related to supervision"?

Comment: You should have found your interest elsewhere before accepting the offer of your current PI because they have already rejected other applicants, and opening another position may waste a lot of their time. You also benefited from their resources for nothing, as you just said you have nothing no publish yet. I am afraid you may not have a solid impression in their mind, thereby better trying to get letters from someone else.

Comment: To answer everyone! First of all promotor is the main professor of the group. He was my direct supervisor in my master studies. Now, in my PhD, I have another supervisor between me and the promotor. I didn't want to explain more about why I don't want to continue, otherwise the post would have been very long and the question would have been closed due to individual factors. When I say "reasons related to supervison", it refers to bad direction by the current supervisor.

Comment: @User Please don't assume anything about why I want to leave the PhD. Please focus on the question. At this moment, all I can share is that I accepted the PhD knowing that I was going to research in my area of interest. Problems can occur from the supervison side as well. I've just mentioned the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: I edited some of the clarifications provided in your comments into your question. It would be good if you could also clarify what is the role of the promotor _towards_ you (I understand he is the head of the team; however, is he just the head of the team you are in and somebody you worked with in the past, or does 'promotor' entail some more formal role towards you as a PhD student)?

Answer (score 1):

If you say that your promotor is very kind and considerate person, I tend not to think that your recommendation letter request will change them and, moreover, influence the review process. So just explain why you took this decision, what motivated you and I believe you two will understand each other.