# Template for follow up mail after no response for a letter of recommendation?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, recommendation-letter

I am currently applying to graduate school and trying to gather some solid letters of recommendation. I already contacted three professors (almost 1 month before application deadline) and 2/3 gladly accepted. The third professor that didn't reply at all already wrote me LoR one year ago so I don't see why he wouldn't like to do it again. How do I ask again without being pushy? Can someone help me what should I write in follow up mail?

Comment: Even one month might be pretty short.

Comment: Not really @AnonymousM

Comment: "_The third professor that didn't reply at all_" Please note that Covid is not gone yet.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably no template, and it would probably sound insincere anyway. Apologize for asking again so soon, but remind them that there is a deadline. If they can't write for you or don't reply, move on.

But, you might also ask their department whether there is some reason they *can't* reply.

And look for an alternative.

Also see: [How should I phrase an important question that I need to ask a professor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/90725/75368)