# How to politely tell a professor you're no longer looking for a project?

Tags: communication, professionalism

(I'm a master's student)

I had approached a professor for an opportunity to work on a project of his, which I found very interesting. When we discussed that opportunity, he deflected my questions about funding. I hadn't promised him that I'll work, but hadn't conclusively said no either, because funding was still possible.

Because of the non-commitment, I approached another professor who is ready to fund my work in their lab.

The first professor has contacted me now to ask when I'll start working. Meanwhile I know from other students that he isn't funding new students in his lab.
How do I tell him, that I am no longer looking to work with him ***without burning bridges***?

The problem is, I was the one actively seeking them out initially.

(Don't assume the prof is a reasonable person - they're a well-regarded researcher in my field though)

Comment: Under most circumstances you won't *burn bridges* when telling you are no longer interested or even when telling that you found something else. They may be less inclined to offer something the next time, but a polite answer that you are no longer interested usually won't offend a professor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would just say that I was unable to work with him at this time as you'd agreed to another project with the necessary funding. You don't need to say a lot, nor to apologize. You could end, if you like, with a statement that some opportunity for collaboration might arise in the future and you would welcome it.

I hope the other project and its funding are secure, though. Otherwise you are taking some risk. Make sure that is settled before you do anything else.

Answer (score 4):

[How should I phrase an important question that I need to ask a professor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90725/how-should-i-phrase-an-important-question-that-i-need-to-ask-a-professor) has good practical tips for actually conveying the message.

As far as the specifics of your situation and not burning bridges, no bridge has been built yet. No relationship was created where you are to start working. You can simply let the professor know you're pursuing something else.

Might he get upset? I suppose. Some people feel ownership over things they don't own, or are egotistical to the point they can't understand why someone would ever pass up the once in a lifetime opportunity to work with them. If this professor is one of those people, better not to worry about their illness and focus on yourself. If they're any other reasonable person, they'll be happy for direct communication that prevents them from wasting any time trying to work with someone who has gone a different direction, and they won't hold any hard feelings over it.

Answer (score -1):

My personal view on this is that the message is what the message is, and I don't see how it makes much of a difference how exactly the message is transmitted (I assume that the idea to call them a loser or something like this won't cross your mind anyway). In any case it's a pretty standard situation and nothing personal, and I'd assume that the vast majority of professors will take it just like that. I can at least say about myself that the straightest way to say such a thing is the best, but other ways won't do much harm either except that they cost everyone a little bit more of their precious time.