# Where can I find professors online to judge my study tool?

Tags: methodology

I am doing my masters in education in an Arabic speaking country and I have created my own test instrument to use as a pre-test and post-test in an experiment.  However, I was told that I need 4 professors in the same major (English curriculum and teaching methods) to proofread and provide input about my test instrument ... in effect, to use them as "jury members(?)" to guarantee the quality of the content and the suitability of the test.

The problem I now face is that that there aren't any professors in my university with the relevant  major so I have to find professors online. To me it seems  rude to email professors to do such a service because it's normally a paid service, so I was wondering if there was a website specifically for that? In Arabic, this was called رأي الخبراء but I haven't found a similar term in English and I would appreciate any help.

Is there a website for services by professors to proofread a test study tool?
And what is this process of checking the study tool called in English?

Comment: Using Google Translate, the Arabic that the OP includes translates simply as: "opinion of experts".

Comment: In my experience, asking never hurts and more often than you might expect, people are willing and happy to help out. I don't think many professors find it rude to receive such a request, if they are too busy they will probably simply ignore it and go about their day. See https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90725/how-should-i-phrase-an-important-question-that-i-need-to-ask-a-professor for pointers on how such an email request could be phrased.

Comment: Do you have an opportunity to attend a conference in your field? That would be the place where experts in your area congregate.